# Connecting to tcp socket and make query

Tags: php

I have run a TCP server through workerman which loads the database. Now I'm trying to connect to this TCP server, send keywords, make queries to the database, and get the response.

The server is simple and it listens on `tcp://127.0.0.1:7000`. I have this on the server part which "waits" for the client to send the keyword

```
$DB = new DB();
$DB->load();

$api->get('/keyword/{name}', function ($request, $name)   use ($DB) {
    $res =  $DB->db($name);
    return $res;
});
```

And here is the client part which I believe is the problem

```
    try {
        $search = $request->input('search'); // multiple keywords
        $searches = explode("\r\n", $search);
        foreach ($searches as $keyword) {
            $url = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:7000/keyword/'.$keyword;
            $fp = fsockopen($url);
            
            fwrite($fp, $keyword);
            $results = fread($fp, 8192);

            return $results;
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response($e->getMessage(), 500);
    }
```

I see that there is a "hit" on the server

```
1 workers       2 processes
worker_name  exit_status      exit_count
none         0                0
----------------------------------------------PROCESS STATUS---------------------------------------------------
pid memory  listening            worker_name  connections send_fail timers  total_request qps    status
748273  682.97M tcp://127.0.0.1:7000 none         0           0         0       3             0      [idle]
748274  682.97M tcp://127.0.0.1:7000 none         0           0         0       2             0      [idle]
----------------------------------------------PROCESS STATUS---------------------------------------------------
Summary 1364M   -                    -            0           0         0       5             0      [Summary]
```

Total requests = 5.

But for some reason, I don't get anything on the client `return $results;`

Is this the correct way to open, send, and receive something from a TCP socket?

UPDATE:

I have changed the client to

```
$fp = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_connect($fp, '127.0.0.1', 7000);

$message = "/keyword/{$keyword}\r\n";
socket_write($fp, $message);
$response = socket_read($fp, 8192);
```

Now says that path is wrong. I guess meaning the path on the server side: `$api->get('/keyword/{name}'`

UPDATE2:

This is how I tried now:

```
    try {
        $fp = fsockopen('tcp://127.0.0.1', 7000, $errno, $errstr, 30);
        if (!$fp) {
            throw new \Exception("Error opening socket: $errstr ($errno)");
        }
        
        // Send the keyword as a GET request
        $url = 'http://127.0.0.1:7000/keyword/'.$search;

        $response = '';
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $response = file_get_contents($url);
        }
        fclose($fp); 
        return $response;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response($e->getMessage(), 500);
    }
```

The error is

> file_get_contents(http://127.0.0.1:7000/keyword/Jake): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

> file_get_contents(http://127.0.0.1:7000/keyword/bo): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
> :Request 4: 60.661055ms

> file_get_contents(http://127.0.0.1:7000/keyword/jen): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
> :Request 5: 66.206243ms

Comment: From the [fsockopen docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) it looks like you're constructing it incorrectly. Looks like it wants the $url to be split up.

Comment: Reading the docs, I see `socket_write` expects a length. Try passing `strlen($message)` as a third parameter.

Comment: @Jaquarh The length is optional, it defaults to the length of `$message`.

Comment: Ahh, seen below in the details. Interesting to know! Thanks! @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using HTTP protocol to connect to the server. `$api->get()` presumably expects to process an HTTP `GET <url>` request.

```
$url = 'http://127.0.0.1:7000/keyword/'.$keyword;
$response = file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: Hey @Barmar, thanks for the answer. Is this mean that I must change the `$api->get()` since I want to process the request/response through TCP, not through HTTP?

Comment: HTTP runs over TCP. TCP is the transport protocol, HTTP is the application protocol.

Comment: Meaning on the client I should have TCP connect and after the connection is done  HTTP GET a request?

Comment: Yes. That's what `file_get_contents()` does by default

Comment: It makes sense now. I have changed it with `file_get_contents()` but got the error that it failed to open the stream. I have updated my question with the latest code that I have. Can you check and if you have some suggests? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what `$api` is, I was making assumptions that it comes from a framework for writing HTTP controllers in PHP.